# Include Class in Source File Rather Than Header

Tags: c++

I have 3 classes:

ClassA.h

```
ClassA
{
    public:
        ClassA();
};
```

ClassB.h

```
#include "ClassA.h"

classB
{
    public:
        ClassB();

    private:
        ClassA m_classA;
};
```

ClassC.h

```
#include "ClassB.h"

ClassC
{
    public:
        ClassC();

    private:
        ClassB m_classB;
};
```

ClassC needs ClassB and ClassB needs ClassA. ClassC doesn't need ClassA so should I put the #include "ClassA.h" that's inside the ClassB header inside the source file and make a global object or is there a better way?

ClassB.cpp

```
#include "ClassB.h"
#include "ClassA.h"

ClassA g_classA;
```

Comment: @Rapptz forward declarations don't declare complete types, he is not using pointers.

Comment: @Nick I seemed to have misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClassB` has a `ClassA` object, so its class declaration needs the full declaration of `ClassA`. So you need to include the `ClassA.h` header in `ClassB.h`<sup>*</sup>, regardless of what happens with `ClassC`.

If you want to avoid including headers what you can do is store a (smart) pointer to `classA` and forward declare it. Then you only need to include `classA.h` in `classB.cpp`. Here is a simple example:

in  `A.h`

```
class A {};
```

in `B.h`

```
#include <unique_ptr>

class A; // forward declaration of A

class B {
 public:
  B();
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<A> a_; // C++11 smart pointer expressing unique ownership
};
```

in `B.cpp`

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h" // we need the full declaration here.

B::B() : a_(new A()) {}
```

<sup>* Strictly speaking, `ClassA.h` could be included in other files as long as it is indirectly included in `ClassB.h`. But it is better to include what you need where you need it, and not depend on indirect includes.</sup>

Comment: Absolutely true for the code as written, but... you can use pimpl to break the dependency.

Comment: Including `ClassA.h` *before* `ClassB.h` works just as well as including it *inside* `ClassB.h`. This might be good advice, but it's not the only way.

Comment: @MarkRansom True, I added a footnote on that.

Comment: If you were working on a large project and ClassB started to grow larger with multiple classes being included, would you still include all these headers inside ClassB's header and create the objects there. Or include the headers inside ClassB's source file and make global class objects and skip the header declarations?

Comment: @JamesMoore "global class objects" is an orthogonal concept. With a data member of a certain type, like you have, each instance of the containing class has its own instance of the contained type. If you want to minimise compile-time dependencies, what you can do is have your classes hold (smart) pointers to other types, and forward declare those types in the header instead of including their header. Then include the header in the source file. I will add a small example.

Comment: Nice, works great. I think you meant to put a B constructor in class B.